# One site with multiple logins or multiple sites

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-storage

I am developing an app with the potential for a large number of customers. Each customer will need access to only their information. However, this information will be regularly accessed through the day and mustn't be shared with other customers. Whilst I am intending on using Azure to share a single database, I can't decide if I should use one website to cope with the uses and have them log in, or provide each customer with their own Azure website; probably with authentication in any case.

Cost, of course plays a part in my decision, but it would seem that having a single web solution would make updates, bug fixes, etc, easier to deploy once, instead of one for each customer. Each customer being separate will mane that they don't have to all be running the same version though.

The images will be stored on an Azure Storage account too.

Does anyone have any experience of this sort of multi-customer deployment scenario or a particular view that I might have missed?

Many thanks,

Jason

Comment: I won't answer because I have no experience on this; but I'd say you can do it by managing permissions in the database. It would be a little like permissions in an operating system -- you have users and groups, and related to them are permissions that grant or revoke the right of Creating / Reading / Updating / Deleting.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you touched all major issues:

1. A single site is easier to maintain.
2. Licenses might be cheaper for a single site than for multipule sites.
3. A single site enforces one version to all clients.

So I guess its a matter of priorities.

On a related note: while using a single DB to all costumers is easier to maintain and cheaper,
it might lead to nasty bugs , so I would take that into consideartion as well.

Comment: Would you recommended have one DB for the site content and another for authentication?